# Phantom hangs on home page

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

I have this code as test.js:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

console.log('The default user agent is ' + page.settings.userAgent);
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0';

//page.onResourceRequested = function(request) {};
//page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {};

page.open('http://www.skadden.com',function(status){
  console.log("Status: " + status);
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Why does Phantom intermittently hang when I run these commands?

```
phantomjs --debug=true --web-security=false --load-images=true test.js
```

Hangs at *[DEBUG] Network - Resource request error: 203 ( "Error downloading http://www.skadden.com/sites/all/themes/skadden_main/images/menu_links.png - server replied: Not Found" ) URL: "http://www.skadden.com/sites/all/themes/skadden_main/images/menu_links.png"*

```
phantomjs --debug=true --web-security=false --load-images=false test.js
```

Works sometimes but will also hang at *[DEBUG] CookieJar - Saved "has_js=1; domain=www.skadden.com; path=/"*

Uncommenting the requested and received handlers causes it to hang less often (don't know why), but it still hangs at the same debug lines. Messing with the user agent, even setting it to blank, also helps but it still hangs sometimes. Obviously, there are many variations that can be tried as far as using the handlers, altering the user agent, and flipping the phantom cli args on and off. Ultimately, I can't find a 100% trustworthy combination. It's a bit frustrating. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated as I really need to crawl this site and currently I cannot.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problems. I tried your script at least 10 times without any problem. I'm running version 1.9.8 on Win7.

Comment: I'm on Linux.  I'm tried it using Phantom v1.9.0 and 1.9.8.